# Not contained in eaggregate function/ the GROUP BY AND max date does not show the latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stucked here and your help will be appreciated. Based on the code that you see below:
I have a sub query with some conditions. especifically, the following:

```
AND OwnedByTeamJ='C - O Review'
AND  OwnedByTeamJ is null
```

I want to get the results from the subquery,
Do another select on them because all I want is the latest date listed the table. As you can see in the picture, I want to be able to extract row#3 which has the highest date and its own by the team which is null (I guess! since there is no value there).
Now the problems:
1-at first the code worked and I saw all the records! though, it didsn't pick the latest date

2- sudennly it stopped working and saw this error:
Column 'tt.IncidentID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
select 
    distinct max(LastModifiedDateTimeJ),
    incidentID,
    EffecRequestStatus,
    OwnedByTeamJ
From (
    select   
      EffecRequestStatus,
      IncidentID,
      LastModifiedDateTimeJ,
      OwnedByTeamJ,
      DetailsJ,
      Status,
      OwnedByTeam 
    from IncidentView
       where 
       CAST(CreatedDateTime as  DATE) >='05-01-2019'
       AND JournalTypeName like '%Journal - Note%'
       AND OwnedByTeamJ='C - O Review'
       AND  OwnedByTeamJ is null

    group by  
        EffecRequestStatus,
        IncidentID,
        LastModifiedDateTimeJ,
        OwnedByTeamJ,
        DetailsJ,
        Status,
        OwnedByTeam
) as tt
where 
    tt. RequestStatus not in ('Submission','P-C submission','C Review')
```

A sample of data look like the following but my table has more columns than that is listed here:

[image]

Comment: if you use and with is null and any value it is always an empty result. You may want an OR in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) These conditions should not coexist:

```
AND OwnedByTeamJ='C - O Review'
AND  OwnedByTeamJ is null
```

...because these two things are never true at the same time, and you will get an empty result-set. I guess what you want is
`AND (OwnedByTeamJ='C - O Review' or OwnedByTeamJ is null)`

2) The error you mention does not seem to agree with the query you've shown us. Did you try to make another `group by` externally?

3) It doesn't make sense to use `distinct` together with any aggregation function like `max`,`sum`, `count` etc.

4) As long as you have included EffecRequestStatus within the `group by`, you will get 3 rows, not 1, because all 3 rows have a different value for EffecRequestStatus. You will have to remove it from the `group by`, and therefore from the `select` as well, if you only want to see one row.

Comment: thanks for taking your time to exolain this. @George Menoutis

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want to have a not empty result:

```
AND (OwnedByTeamJ='C - O Review'
OR  OwnedByTeamJ is null)
```